# can one matrix have 2 inverses?

Tags: matrices

can this matrix have 2 inverse?

$$\left(\begin{matrix}-0.173796&0.003408&0.170298&0.052286&-0.000000&-0.000000\\
0.063304&0.011593&-0.090665&-0.000000&0.000000&-0.000000\\
-0.063304&0.014688&0.032038&0.045021&0.000000&-0.000000\\
0.744675&-0.819019&-0.586578&-0.586578&-0.586578&0.697076\\
0.406416&0.768870&-0.292017&-0.292017&-0.292017&-0.841471\\
1.178726&-0.441200&-1.211953&-1.211953&-1.211953&0.440430\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: No, inverses, if they exist, are unique.

Comment: If it has an inverse, it is unique.

Answer (score 5):

Assume $A,B$ to be two inverses of $M$, i.e. $AM=MA=I$ and $BM=MB=I$ Then we see
$$A=AI=A(MB)=(AM)B=IB=B$$

---

In your case the inverse is computed by MATLAB to be
$$\left(\begin{matrix}-430.3686&-631.7518&499.8168&-9.1408&-4.6680&5.5488\\
 -642.4617&-943.0901&746.1352&-19.9527&-10.1893&12.1121\\
 -382.6406&-572.7200&444.3870&-8.9336&-4.5621&5.4230\\
 -123.2433&-173.0638&165.3428&0.0140&0.0071&-0.0085\\
   85.3620&128.4863&-121.3487&0.1671&-0.2982&-0.8341\\
 -648.9572&-952.6250&753.6788&-19.6087&-11.0689&12.1575\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: If you leave out the redundant $=(MA)B$ then elegance is gained.

Comment: @drhab elegance was gained. Thanks a lot.